# Session value get deleted on page refresh in ci

Tags: codeigniter

I have a login function. When I login, the session gets saved. But when I refresh the page or redirect to another function, then the session (userdata) is shown blank. I have loaded the session library in autoload, but the userdata is deleted after every page refresh.

Here is my code.

```
public function index () {
$user = $this->input->post('user');
// after successful user checking
$this->session->set_userdata('user', $user);
// when I print session here,
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
// session user gets print
}
```

But when I redirect to a function (suppose 'test'), then no any session is shown.

```
public function test() {
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
die;
}
```

Comment: **Note:** Codeigniter by default uses Cookie-based mechanism so it's provides limited storage. If you want to extend the storage limit you can configure it to store session data in database. Check CI Documentation.

Comment: Ya but I'm not storing excessive data in session that my session gets deleted.

Comment: Ok than try to debug in both functions using `print_r($this->session);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Actually, accidentally I had destroyed the session at the beginning of the code. So, my session was all destroyed. I removed the code and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you read the post value with $this->input->post('user'); and there isn't any post the function returns null and save this in the user value.

You have to check before setting.

```
    if ($this->input->post('user')) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('username',  $this->input->post('user'));
    }
```

Comment: No, there is no any post function that returns null. I have checked the value. The value is fetched successfully and stored in the session successfully, but when I refresh the page, the values stored in the session are all removed.

Comment: Are you sending the post value every time?